# Can this sql query be simplified?

Tags: sql, simplify

I have a Sql Query:

```
select * from contactmeta
WHERE
contactmeta.contact_id in 
(
select tob.object_id from tagobject tob, tag t, taggroup tg 
where tob.tag_id = t.tag_id
and t.tag_group_id = tg.tag_group_id
and tob.object_type_id = 14 
and tg.org_id = contactmeta.group_id 
and (t.name like '%campaign%')
)
AND
contactmeta.contact_id in 
(
select tob.object_id from tagobject tob, tag t, taggroup tg 
where tob.tag_id = t.tag_id 
and t.tag_group_id = tg.tag_group_id
and tob.object_type_id = 14 
and tg.org_id = contactmeta.group_id 
and (t.name like '%bounced%')
)
```

My problem is that I need to simplify the part of the query inside the WHERE clause (I cannot make another join with the contactmeta table etc.). This is because the WHERE clause is dynamically created on an otherwise static sql.

You can see that both the where condition is almost same except for the t.name condition.

Thanks for your time

SK

Comment: There is another difference in your sub-queries.  The first has t.tag_group_id = tg.tag_group_id, the second doesn't.

Comment: @rayd09: I think that is just copy&paste error as the second subquery has `tob.tag_id = t.tag_id` twice.

@Samuel: is this true? or is the query in your question indeed correct?

Comment: Yes this is a cut and paste error... sorry about this... let me see if I can edit it.

Comment: okay corrected the query

Answer (score 2):

this isn't really any simpler (in terms of code) but will be more performant, since you are using joins rather than the `IN` operator:

```
select contactmeta .* from contactmeta 

inner join tagobject tob, tag t, taggroup tg  
on tob.tag_id = t.tag_id 
and t.tag_group_id = tg.tag_group_id 
and tob.object_type_id = 14  
and tg.org_id = contactmeta.group_id  
and (t.name like '%campaign%')

inner join tagobject tob2, tag t2, taggroup tg2  
on tob2.tag_id = t2.tag_id 
and t2.tag_group_id = tg2.tag_group_id 
and tob2.object_type_id = 14  
and tg2.org_id = contactmeta.group_id  
and (t2.name like '%bounced%')
```

**EDIT**: if that is not possible (due to your comments about `JOIN` limitations), then you could abstract part of the logic into views e.g.

```
create view myView 
as
select * from tagobject tob, tag t, taggroup tg  
    on tob.tag_id = t.tag_id 
    and t.tag_group_id = tg.tag_group_id
```

and then use that view in your original sql.

Comment: @davek: OP writes they cannot change the query structure, but need a solution for the WHERE clause.

Comment: One possible problem with the first solution here is that, while th OP's current query would only return one entry from contactmeta, here there may be multiple results if the two inner joins return different numbers of records.

Comment: View idea is good. I will use it if I cannot make it simpler any other way.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, the sub-selects in your WHERE clause are not the same.

I am unsure what you mean by "simplified", simplified in what way? Less verbose? Less complex query plan? More performance? In other words, what problem are you trying to solve?

Some ideas:

- You could create a view for your
  sub-select (or sub-selects if the
  difference between the two is on
  purpose) which would reduce the
  verboseness.
- Get the query plan of the query and
  look for table scans.
- Consider using full text indexing
  rather than LIKE with a wild card at
  the beginning of the pattern as this
  requires the entire index to be
  scanned (assuming there is an index
  on the column) -- if there isn't an
  index then add one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from contactmeta
WHERE
contactmeta.contact_id in 
(
select tob.object_id from tagobject tob, tag t, taggroup tg 
where tob.tag_id = t.tag_id
and tob.object_type_id = 14 
and tg.org_id = contactmeta.group_id 
and (
   (t.tag_group_id = tg.tag_group_id and t.name like '%campaign%')
   or
   (tob.tag_id = t.tag_id and t.name like '%bounced%')
)
)
```

Comment: I don't think this is the same, although at first I thought the same. The OP's query matches rows that have both at least one row with "campaign" **and** at least one row with "bounced". Your query already matches rows that have **either** "campaign" **or** "bounced" (or both), but doesn't **require** both.

Comment: not quite correct.  His query would have to join the contactmeta with (tag/tagobject/taggroup) twice because of the AND condition for the 2 names.

Comment: ** Sorry this was cut and paste mistake. everything is same except for the t.name clause **

Comment: sorry corrected the query. Note that everything is same except for the t.name line